# How to retrieve data between two <br/> tags

Tags: c#, regex, dom

I want to get the data between the two `<br/>` tags.

The data in xml file is like this `<br/>lots of data<br/>`.

Now I want to get the data between the two `<br/>` tags and fetch specific data in it.

Can anyone suggest me how to search the tags and fetch the specific data between them?

Comment: It's XML... use an XML parser that's already in the framework...

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use some LINQ to XML here to do this.

Example:

```
var xmlStr = @"<root>
    data1<br/>
    data2<br/>
    data3<br/>
    data4<br/>
    data5<br/>
</root>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
var query =
    from br in doc.Descendants("br")
    let textNode = br.NextNode as XText
    where textNode != null
    let nextBr = textNode.NextNode as XElement
    where nextBr != null && nextBr.Name == "br"
    select textNode.Value;
```

Comment: Hi, Jeff. The data is in xml file which was converted from html.I need to access data from that file and search the specific data.

Answer (score 1):

***LINQ to XML approach is fairly more approachable than this as [Jeff Mercado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado)'s answer. As using RegEx is not recommended for parsing XML data. But if your requirement is for one time only then it might help.***

```
(?is)(?<=^|<br/>).*?(?=<br/>)
```

Comment: It is not showing any results.